# Inline Python how to convert filter objects from Python to arrays or iterator at least in Perl

Tags: python, arrays, perl, nlp, iterator

I'm using spacy with Inline::Python in Perl and I end up with filter object and i have absolutly no idea how to use it, first, and how to convert it to array, second. I've tried grep, map, join, but nothing, still a filter object. I can't use list because the data flow is too important.
Here is my piece of code :

```
use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON';

import spacy
from spacy.lang.fr.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as fr_stop
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')
nlp.max_length = 40000000

fr_stop = set(fr_stop)
def lemmatizer(words):
    doc = nlp(words)
    yield from filter(lambda x: x not in fr_stop, map(lambda token: token.lemma_ , doc))

END_OF_PYTHON
```

Do you have any idea or other solution like IPC::Run I don't know.

Comment: This is a follow up to an earlier Q&A. When I saw the earlier Q, I thought "why not just use a pipe?" This is simple string in, string out interface, which can easily be done using pipes. But the implementation would depend on specifics: Do you call `lemmatizer` more than once per process? And if not, do you want to use an argument or a pipe for the input?

Comment: The Perl sub `lemmatizer` returns the *string* `<generator object lemmatizer at 0x7fc87ca8fbf8>`. The module doesn't support generator objects (what `lemmatizer` actually returns) and returns a stringification of it.

Comment: thx for the answer. Yes i use it a lot and it makes my script slow as hell.  How to implement the pipe you think about ? I'm curious and interested.

Comment: no once per process at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much overhead Inline::Python adds, but it's entirely overkill here.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $in = ...;

utf8::encode($in);

run [ "lemmatizer.py" ], \$in, \$out
   or die($?);

utf8::decode($out);
my @lemmas = split /\n/, $out;
```

You can even avoid loading the entire response into memory at once.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $in = ...;

utf8::encode($in);

run([ "lemmatizer.py" ],
   '<', \$in,
   '>', new_chunker, sub {
      my $lemma = shift;
      utf8::decode($lemma);
      ...
   },
)
   or die($?);
```

On the Python side, simply read from STDIN until EOF and decode from UTF-8 to get the input, and send the output by writing each lemma encoded using UTF-8 as a separate line.